# Change color of div according to countdown

Tags: javascript, jquery

I didn't know how to word this properly, but I have a countdown, and I want the color to go from green to red, gradually (like a gradient if that makes sense) as the timer counts down. So when it's 25 minutes it's green, and it completes its change to red as it hits 00:00:00.

I know you can change it based on time but I couldn't find a solution for a gradual change.

I tried the following JS and then calling `changeColor()` upon clicking "go" but it's a bit of a mess, stops the countdown from working and I don't know where to go from here:

```
function changeColor() {
    if (document.getElementById("time").innerHTML === "00:00:00") {
        $("#tomato").css("background-color", "#37bd5b");
    } else if (document.getElementById("time").innerHTML !== "00:00:00") {
        $("#tomato").css("background-color", "#D71F27");
}
```

Here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4w967gfp/16/), I want the red bg to start changing upon clicking go.

**EDIT:** I eventually want to add in the ability to change the minutes on the countdown.

Comment: simplest solution is use css background-color transition.

Comment: You could experiment with rgb values. Plot a course from red to green and have the rgb values adjust accordingly with every passing second. It may be a bit resource intensive if you have a long count down, since the browser will be applying a change, or repainting, every second. But just an idea. Also, if this timer is going to be dynamic, you'll need to consider how you'll scale that transition from red to green. But the idea would be to have each rgb value stored as a variable that you can progressively change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the jquery `animate` function. First include jquery ui so that the color feature works. Then get the time when you click go.

```
var pieces = startTime.split(":");
var time = new Date();
time.setHours(pieces[0]);
time.setMinutes(pieces[1]);
time.setSeconds(pieces[2]);
var timerSec=time.getSeconds()+time.getMinutes()*60+time.getHours()*3600;
$('#tomato').animate({
  backgroundColor: "#00e50b"
}, timerSec*1000);
```

In the `reset` click you also need to add

```
$('#tomato').stop();
$('#tomato').attr('style', 'background-color:#D72028');
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4w967gfp/24/)-I changed the time in the fiddle to be shorter and easier to see the results.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/4w967gfp/19/)?

Function:

```
function set_background(value)
{
    var hue = ((1-value)*120).toString(10);
  return ["hsl(",hue,",100%,50%)"].join("");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We know that green in rgb is rgb(0, 255, 00), and that red is rgb(255, 0, 0). You have however many seconds there are in 25 minutes -- 1500 seconds. You want to use:

```
$("#div-id").css("background-color","rgb(x, y, 0)");
```

to set the background of the color, where x and y should be between 0 and 255.

if the current count in seconds is 1500, we want x = 255 and y = 0. If the count is 0, we want x = 0 and y = 255.

We need to find the linear factor that we'll multiply the count by to get 255 when the count is 1500.

```
1500 * factor = 255
factor = 0.17
```

So, if at each count, we multiply by 0.17, we will get a number in between 0 and 255 for the red in the rgb background color.

```
1500*0.17 = 255
750 * 0.17 = 127.5
0 * 0.17 = 0
```

That works out for red. For green, we want to reverse the behavior. At 1500, we want the value to be 0.

```
(1500-curCount) * 0.17 = greenVal
```

If curCount = 1500, we get a greenVal of 0. If curCount is 0, we get a greenVal of 255. If curCount is 750, we get a greenVal of 127.5.

So, each time the count is decreased, use the two equations I showed above to calculate the green and red values, and use the jquery statement above to set the div's background color to the resulting color.

Comment: I think I can experiment with this, thanks! I can image it'd be much more complicated if the user could change the minutes on the countdown.

Comment: @l-emi not necessarily. Calculate the number of seconds in the countdown based on the minutes they choose, and store the result in a variable. Use that variable in the above equations instead of the 1500. You can also use it to calculate the factor to multiply by because it's just `255/maxSeconds`. With that said, I think you went with the right choice using the animate function.